# PHP 5.3 $this versus PHP 5.4

Tags: php

I am calling a member function inside an anonymous function using $this.

```
 $this->exists($str)
```

PHP 5.4 does not give me problems, 5.3 gives me problems.

The error is

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Using $this when not in object context in
```

Here is my code

```
class WordProcessor
{

private function exists($str)
{
 //Check if word exists in DB, return TRUE or FALSE
 return bool;
}

private function mu_mal($str)
{

    if(preg_match("/\b(mu)(\w+)\b/i", $str))
    {   $your_regex = array("/\b(mu)(\w+)\b/i" => "");      
        foreach ($your_regex as $key => $value) 
            $str = preg_replace_callback($key,function($matches)use($value)
            {
                if($this->exists($matches[0])) //No problems in PHP 5.4, not working in 5.3
                    return $matches[0];
                if($this->exists($matches[2]))
                    return $matches[1]." ".$matches[2];
                 return $matches[0];
            }, $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `$this` inside of a closure which is executed in a separate context.

At the beginning of your `mu_mal` function, you should declare `$that = $this` (or something like `$wordProcessor` to be more explicit about what the variable is). Then, inside of your `preg_replace_callback`'s closure, you should add `use ($that)` and reference `$that` inside of your closure instead of `$this`.

```
class WordProcessor
{

    public function exists($str)
    {
        //Check if word exists in DB, return TRUE or FALSE
        return bool;
    }

    private function mu_mal($str)
    {
        $that = $this;

        if(preg_match("/\b(mu)(\w+)\b/i", $str))
        {
            $your_regex = array("/\b(mu)(\w+)\b/i" => "");      
            foreach ($your_regex as $key => $value) 
                $str = preg_replace_callback($key,function($matches)use($value, $that)
                {
                    if($that->exists($matches[0])) //No problems in PHP 5.4, not working in 5.3
                        return $matches[0];
                    if($that->exists($matches[2]))
                        return $matches[1]." ".$matches[2];
                    return $matches[0];
                }, $str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

**Note that you have to expose `exists` to the public API of the class (which I have done above)**

This behavior was changed in PHP 5.4